# Terraform Data Source conditional

Tags: terraform

I am looking to return the ami id of existing ec2 instances but if ec2 doesnt exist it should be created. Below is my terraform module code.

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ec2_name]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  #ami            = var.ami_lookup != true ? var.ec2_ami : "testing"
  ami           = var.ec2_ami
  instance_type = var.ec2_type
  subnet_id     = var.ec2_subnet
  iam_instance_profile = var.iam_role
  vpc_security_group_ids  = var.security_groups
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.ebs_size
    volume_type  = "gp3"
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = true
    tags = {
      Name = var.ec2_name
      backup = var.backup
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.ec2_name
    env  = var.ec2_env
    backup = var.backup
    replication = var.replication
    downtime = var.downtime
    site_name = var.ec2_name
  }
}
```

The terraform code works for existing resources but if I try to add a new resource the terraform plan fails due to the empty data resource.

Comment: Its not possible, as this is not how TF works.

Comment: Get rid of the data source all together, and import any existing EC2 instances into your Terraform state. That's the only way to do this sort of thing with Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is a "desired state" system, so *you* must tell Terraform whether you intend it to manage an object itself or to depend on an object managed by some other system (which could be another Terraform configuration or not Terraform at all).

If you need to write a module that can support both cases then a relatively simple way to do it is to declare an optional input variable which, when specified, represents the existing object to use:

```
variable "existing_instance_id" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

data "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = var.existing_instance_id != null ? 1 : 0

  id = var.existing_instance_id
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = var.existing_instance_id == null ? 1 : 0

  # ...
}

locals {
  # This allows you to use local.ec2_instance_id elsewhere in
  # your module to refer to the EC2 instance ID regardless of
  # whether it is managed in this module or not.
  ec2_instance_id = coalesce(
    data.aws_instance.example,
    aws_instance.example,
  ).id
}
```

When calling this module, the caller can choose whether or not to set `existing_instance_id`. If they set it then the module will declare that it depends on that existing object, and if they don't set it then the module will declare that it will manage an EC2 instance itself.

Another way to do it is to decompose into smaller modules and have this main module *always* expect to be passed an EC2 instance by its caller, and then the caller can decide whether to use a `data` block or a `resource` block to declare it. There's an example of that in [Conditional Creation of Objects](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition#conditional-creation-of-objects) in [the Module Composition guide](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition).